# Analysis and real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

Let $X$ and $Y$ be compact metric spaces. Let $X\times Y = \{(x; y) \,:\, x \in X;\, y \in Y \} $be the cartesian product. Show that any $f \in C(X \times Y )$ can be uniformly approximated by
functions of the form
$\sum_{i=1}^n f_i(x)g_i(y)$, where $f_i\in C(X)$ and $g_i\in C(Y )$.

Comment: This can be obtained as a corollary to the Stone-Weierstrass theorem. Are you familiar with this theorem?

Comment: I guess you meant $g_i(y)$ instead of $g_i(x)$.